# Google Cloud Pub Sub with Apache beam acknowledgement slow

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Apache beam pulls the packets from google cloud pubsub at 30 packets per second but acknowledges only 20 per second. Need to why it happens and how can I limit the packet input per second? We use a window of 20 seconds and pubsub expiry is also 20 seconds.

We use `ReadStringsFromPubSub` to read and `WindowInto` to set rate limit.